# Can an application connect to databases from on-premise SQL Server Instance and Azure SQL together?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Can a single application connect to two different databases each of which is in different Instances. One instance has on-premise deployment, the other one is Azure SQL(not SQL in Azure VM). So basically is it possible for an application to access data from both Instances?

Comment: If the answer will differ for each one then both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use so many connections you need.

For instance, if you're programming for .Net framework simply instantiate two or more [SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.7.2) class and set up the [ConnectionString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.7.2) property according the DB you are trying to access.

You can find some examples about ConnectionString's [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax).

And MS Docs about Azure ConnectionString's [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string).